# ObjC Class Runtime Process +Initialize problem?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

All
I'm trying to understand the obejctive C object runtime process

From the Object Refs , the object's +Initialize method will be called when it first got some method called. I run a test file as below . I wonder why these objects only got the +load called.

```
// InitializeTest.h
@interface InitializeTest : NSObject {
@private
}
- (void) show;
@end


@interface InitializeTest(Category)
+ (void) load;
+ (void) initialize;
@end


@interface InitializeTestSub : InitializeTest {
@private
}
- (void) showSub;
@end

@interface InitializeTestSub(Category)
+ (void) load;
+ (void) initialize;
@end
```

```
//InitializeTest.m
#import "InitializeTest.h"

@implementation InitializeTest
+ (void) load {
    NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,self);
}

+ (void) initialize {
    NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,self);
}

- (void) show {
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
}
@end


@implementation InitializeTest(Category)
+ (void) load {
    NSLog(@"Category %s %@",__func__,self);
}

+ (void) initialize {
    NSLog(@"Category %s %@",__func__,self);
}
@end


@implementation InitializeTestSub
+ (void) load {
    NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,self);
}

+ (void) initialize {
    NSLog(@"%s %@",__func__,self);
}

- (void) showSub {
    NSLog(@"%s",__func__);
}
@end

@implementation InitializeTestSub(Category)
+ (void) load {
    NSLog(@"Category %s %@",__func__,self);
}

+ (void) initialize {
    NSLog(@"Category %s %@",__func__,self);
}
@end
```

```
//test Code
    InitializeTest* test = [[InitializeTest alloc] init];
    InitializeTestSub *testSub = [[InitializeTestSub alloc] init];

    [test class];
    [testSub class];


    [test show];
    [testSub show];
    [testSub showSub];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Result
+[InitializeTest load] InitializeTest
+[InitializeTestSub load] InitializeTestSub
Category +[InitializeTest(Category) load] InitializeTest
Category +[InitializeTestSub(Category) load] InitializeTestSub
-[InitializeTest show]
-[InitializeTest show]
-[InitializeTestSub showSub]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+initialize` is not meant to be used by categories, only the classes themselves. It is possible that the runtime sees two different `+initialize` methods and doesn't run either because of that. See [+initialize](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/initialize) in NSObject's class reference (the Special Considerations section).

Comment: Thank you for the help. So, does that special Conditions mean if you've implemented you class-specific behavior using +load method , the +initialize method won't be called?

Comment: @Celery01 No, it means that +initialize will only be called once per class, unless a subclass doesn't implement it. If it is defined in both a class and category, both will not be called. There is a possibility that the runtime won't call either because there are two implementations.

Comment: I comment both +initialize methods in both category , but the print log still don't get the +initialize out . Is there any other tips on that or some bug in my test code  ?

Comment: OK, so that wasn't right. I looked around and found a page from the GNU runtime which suggests only using load or initialize but not both: (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/objc-features_1.html#SEC3 second to last paragraph in section). It sounds like it should call both and is just advising against it, but it might ignore it too.

Comment: nice References.Thanks a lot.